# Kali Linux: MacBook 207 keyboard only available after boot time

Tags: kali-linux, grub2, kernel-modules

I was happy to see that finally my keyboard works on Kali Linux (USB encrypted persistence boot) using my MacBook Pro 2017. However, what is a bit frustrating is that it is only accessible at two points in time:

1. During the selection of options in GRUB (i.e. live system, persistence, persistence encrypted, i.e.) and
2. Once the Kali OS has successfully booted.

However, they keyboard does not work once one of the GRUB options are set, the kernel is booting and I have to enter my LUKS password.

The keyboard support is probably due to `applespi` kernel module and thus I added this module to various files in order to have it loaded at boot time already. I added it to:

`/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` as well as
`/etc/modules` and
`/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`

However, I cannot get it working. Next thing I wanted to try is to insert the module name into the grub configuration. However, I cannot find the file `/etc/default/grub` in kali.

I am a bit lost. Any ideas how to proceed from here?

Comment: After adding it to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` did you rebuild your initramfs?  EG: `update-initramfs -uk all`